# converting optical frame to base frame tf

Tags: ros, frames, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to transform an optical frame -> x=right, y=down, z=forward to a base frame with the orientation -> x=forward, y=left, z=up.

I attempted to try the translation in a tf broadcaster, but was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

System:Ubuntu, Fuerte, Precise

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56146/converting-optical-frame-to-base-frame-tf/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-02-24**:
You need to be more specific about what you mean by unsuccessful. Check out the launch file `kinect_frames.launch` file in `openni_launch` package for an example of how to do exactly what you are asking [here](https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_launch/file/7126145eb885/launch/kinect_frames.launch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly did not work with the tf broadcaster? If the origin is supposed to stay the same, all you need to do is find the right rotation between the frames and broadcast like so:

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
tf::Transform transform;
transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0,0,0)); 
transform.setRotation( tf::Quaternion(x,y,z,w) ); 
br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "optical", "base_link"));
```

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-25**:
Thanks, I was on the right track...I just wasn't sending the right angles.